# Render as PDF page orientation

Tags: visualforce, css, style

I'm trying to have both portrait (page one) and landscape (page two) in a visualforce page which is 'render as PDF'.
I have tried various options but cannot get it to work, I can only get all landscape or all portrait, here is the code, please help!

```html
<apex:page Controller="RAMS_Controller" showHeader="false" renderas="pdf" applyBodyTag="false" applyHtmlTag="false">
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                @page{
                    size: A4 landscape;
                }
            </style>
    <div style="text-align:center;">
        <p style="text-align:center;font-size: 25px"><font face="Arial">Page One</font></p>
    </div>

    <div style="text-align:center;">
    
        <p style="text-align:center;font-size: 25px"><font face="Arial">Page Two</font></p>
    </div>
```

There is closing tags in the above code, but I can't get them to show on the page!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/613971/2132791), you can alias different sizes (`@page aliasName`):

```
@page land { size:landscape; }
@page port { size:portrait; }
```

Which you can then apply via the `page` CSS attribute:

```
.landscapePage { page:land; }
.portraitPage { page:port; }
```

Which in turn renders the pages as you desire:

```
<div class="portraitPage">
    <p>Some page content in portrait</p>
</div>
<div class="landscapePage">
    <p>Some page content in landscape</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a bit easier than what I worked out, using one `@page` to set the overall orientation, then using `@page :first` to override that orientation for just the first page. More flexible too. Also confirmed that both approaches do indeed work on Salesforce.